# Thinking of all possible responses after walking away from an argument

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

I am searching for a phrase for the feeling that you have when you walk away from an argument and think of all the responses that you could have said. I remember that my friend told me that there was a very specific phrase for it, involving "escalier" but I cannot remember the rest. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [*esprit d'escalier*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'esprit_de_l'escalier), which has an interesting origin.

Answer (score 2):

You are certainly thinking about *[l'esprit de l'escalier](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esprit_de_l%27escalier)*.

Comment: Techniquement, j'étais le premier, avec 12 secondes d'avance ;-)

Comment: @Frank Bravo, victoire sur le fil ...

Comment: (On s'en fiche pas mal, bien entendu :-)

Comment: Surtout qu'on est presque d'accord sur la réponse...